# Getting variable outside-name inside Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to work on something that lists objects (no matter how deep) inside data with spacing.

Something like:

```
const data = [1,2,3];
test(data);
Output:
"[
  1,
  2,
  3
]"
```

So far I've worked around all the gimmicks of getting Object variable names etc, so getting stuff like:

```
const data = {a: 1, b: 2};
test(data);

Outputs:
"{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}"
```

So I'm recursively able to loop pretty much anything, and I'm also adding 2nd parameter to able to search for a given key or variable.

So this is already working code, but what I'm missing is that I want to start the print out with object name given to function, something like:

```
const data = "hello";
test(data);

Outputs:
"data: "hello""
```

or

```
const data = {a: 1, b: 2};
test(data);

Outputs:
"data: {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}"
```

I tried Object.keys but I can't access the object name outside function.

I've seen you can do this by assigning the given variable as object in start, like:
test({data});

so this way this generates an object passed through, in which there's a data key and data values.

But I'm just wondering if this can be done without?

I just want to make it as simple as possible for my fellow coding fellows and would prefer the variable passed as is, without adding anything extras.

To avoid any confusion, all I want is to function to start writing the output with variable name (in this example; **data**), starting with "[variable name]: " or as in example "**data**: ", without trying to add curly braces when calling function.

Something like:

```
function getObjectData(o) {
  oName = ...
  console.log(oName + ": " + o)
}
```

And this to be called with simply (again, no curly braces):

```
const data = "hello";
getObjectData(data);
```

And resulting in output:

```
"data: hello"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if the name of the variable is relevant to the data, I would advise storing it along with the data

Comment: Now that's an interesting question - and I don't see why it was down-voted. I tried to declare a constant in a module and they retrieve the list of properties from the `global` object and...my constant is not there. This is interesting because it opens the question: where are constant / variables stored if not in the global object - either `global` or `window`?

Comment: @EricMORAND Neither :P `const`s, `let`s and `class`s declared at the top level (so-called "lexically declared" variables) sit in their own space (ie: environment record), called the "declarative environment". JavaScript doesn't provide a way to "look into" it like we can for `var`/`function` variables stored in the "object environment" through the use of the global object (eg: `window`) (more info [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-global-environment-records), and [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation) is where they get setup)

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickParsons. I've been pretending to know ECMAScript spec very well - I'v e been actually teaching them - and I totally missed that point. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In native JavaScript, variables themselves can't be passed directly into functions. Instead, what gets passed is the value stored in the variable.

However, you can use a workaround by passing an object that holds your variable as a property. This way, you can access both the key (variable name) and value inside the function.

Here's an example:

```
test({data})

function test(obj) {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  const value = obj[key];
  console.log(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something that can do without curly braces.

I saw there was some possibility to try get variable name by looping through window, trying to test this now.

Comment: Your variable will be stored in the `window` variable only if it's a global variable, and even if it is I don't think that looping through all `window` properties is a valid solution. This could lead to a performance hit due to the number of properties, and this method won't work if multiple variables has the same value

Comment: Yeah that would be the case I suppose, so if I make:
const a = "hello", b = "hello";

then technically it'd be possible to get "a: hello" as output when calling "getObjectData(b)", though I'd be quite rare considering most values are vastly different. I suppose I could filter the name out if there was multiple solutions or find other ways to figure out what the exact name is....

Comment: I don't suppose there's anything like: function test(obj: Object) that would define that whatever gets passed into function gets defined as an object, and thus would gain access to the key attribute or the name of the variable.

Comment: That's not possible, the function cannot know the original name of the variable, only the name of the parameter.  So yeah you are stuck with the global method, and if  two properties has the same value you can display both. I don't know your usecase but it seems a little messy.

Comment: and to add on to that, the global method won't work with variables declared using `let`, `const` or `class` (or if you use `var` in a module), even if declared at the top level of your script, so I'd say this is the best alternative.

Comment: Shame, I think it would've been helpful. But I guess if debugging, having object variables passed with {o} wrapped around would then enable to print out at least what's being tested. Though since it's already done by modifying input, it could be easier to just pass name of the variable, along with what's being tested.

My use case would be more about enabling users (developers, testers) to clearly see the content of data, and easily pass the output in message boards, not having to separately copy the variable name. Just a curiosity thing, thanks everyone for answering.

Comment: If it is just for a debugging purpose, using an IDE debugger will provide the variables and their values